# creating a max-heap using java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to create a Max-Heap in java using the following code:

```
public class Heapify {
// 16 14 10 8 7 9 3 2 4 1

    public static int[] Arr = {4, 1, 3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8, 7};
    public static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int kk;
        for (kk = 0; kk <= Arr.length - 1; kk++) {
            heapM(Arr, kk);
        }

        for (int krk = 0; krk < Arr.length; krk++) {
            System.out.println(Arr[krk]);
        }



    }

    public static void heapM(int[] Arr, int i) {

        int largest;
        int left = i * 2;
        int right = i * 2 + 1;
        if (((left < Arr.length) && (Arr[left] > Arr[i]))) {
            largest = left;
        } else {
            largest = i;
        }

        if (((right < Arr.length) && (Arr[right] > Arr[largest]))) {
            largest = right;
        }
        if (largest != i) {
            swap(i, largest);


            heapM(Arr, largest);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int i, int largest) {
        int t = Arr[i];
        Arr[i] = Arr[largest];
        Arr[largest] = t;

    }
}
```

The desired output should be :

```
16 14 10 8 7 9 3 2 4 1
```

Whereas I am getting

```
4 3 16 14 8 9 10 2 1 7
```

Can someone please help as to why the heap is not being built properly ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post code snippets indented readably.

Comment: Thanks Sujay for the formatting , Millimoose sorry about the raw format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran your code, and in addition to what Jodaka said, I found one more error

```
for (kk = 0; kk <= Arr.length - 1; kk++) {
        heapM(Arr, kk);
}
```

should be

```
for (kk = Arr.length -1; kk >= 0; kk--) {
        heapM(Arr, kk);
}
```

because when doing MaxHepify, you start from the end, and go backwards.
and

```
 int left = i * 2;
 int right = i * 2 + 1;
```

should be, as Jodaka said

```
int left = 2*i+1;
int right = 2*i + 2;
```

I ran it here and the output is now correct

Comment: Ah, completely missed that first part.  Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is here:

```
int left = i * 2;
int right = i * 2 + 1;
```

Since java arrays are zero-based, you are saying that the left child of 0 is 0 * 2 = 0!  Fix your logic and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: output is the same even if I change the loop to start from 1

Comment: My point is that you're not calculating the children correctly for ANY node.  I just used 0 as the most obvious example.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (kk = Arr.length -1; kk >= 0; kk--) {
    heapM(Arr, kk);
}
```

should be

```
for (kk = (Arr.length -1)/2; kk >= 0; kk--) {
    heapM(Arr, kk);
}
```

More efficient.

**Edit** This lets you build a heap in O(n) time instead of O(n*lg(n)) time and is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building%5Fa%5Fheap

Comment: Added reference for readers since it is a good answer but not explained enough.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to make a max-heap, you should start from n/2 down to 0 instead of 0 to n. Due to 0 to n what happens is that say in an array like 2 0 1 12 13. The output array after you perform max heap will be 2 13 1 12 0 where as if you call from n/2 down to 0 it will be  13 12 1 2 0.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework? 
If not you can use PriorityQueue of JAVA

Comment: naah , just trying to re-furbish my knowledge