# Partially sort an array in descending order using Java Stream API

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-stream

I need to know how to partially sort an array of primitive unique integers in descending order using Stream API. For example, if there is an array like `{1,2,3,4,5}`, I want to get `{5,4,3, 1,2}` - 3 biggest elements first and then the rest. Is it even possible using streams? I checked the docs - there are two methods `skip` and `limit` but they change the stream content and work from the beginning of the array.

I can sort the whole array like

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
.boxed()
.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
.toArray();
```

but how to make this sorting partial? I said Stream API because I want it to be written nicely.

Also I intuitively feel that `concat` may have a go here. Another approach I could think about - is to use a custom comparator limiting the number of sorted elements. What do you think?

P.S. I am not a Java expert.

Comment: How would you solve it with plain Java? Is the input an array or a set?

Comment: Your example input is `{1,2,3,4,5}`. Is the input guaranteed to be sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Input is an array `int[]`. In plain Java I would use a any well-known algo like insertion sort etc stopping after needed elements get sorted in desc order. The problem is that I need to pass a testcase and using such a naive algo I get timeout.

Comment: Also is it necessary that the "other" elements are in their original order? If not, then wouldn't a normal sort basically solve this? Edit: I just saw your comment about timeout.

Comment: @arcadeblast77 No, I put it in asc order just to highlight what I want. It can be totally random.

Comment: @curveball I highly doubt you will speed up things by rewriting them to Stream API...

Comment: @arcadeblast77 Yes, you are right, implemented normal sorting algos give the result but running testcases I get timeout on big inputs.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Ok, I got it. I tried to implement insertion and selection sort and got timeout. Things like merge/quicksort are faster but the code is pretty messy and verbose. I thought that maybe exists a way using streams...

Comment: Use `Collections.sort()` for mergesort / quicksort / dual-pivot quicksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using streams.

```
int[] sortPartially(int[] inputArray, int limit) {
    Map<Integer, Long> maxValues = IntStream.of(inputArray)
                                            .boxed()
                                            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                                            .limit(limit)
                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));

    IntStream head = maxValues.entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .flatMapToInt(e -> IntStream.iterate(e.getKey(), i -> i)
                                                          .limit(e.getValue().intValue()));

    IntStream tail = IntStream.of(inputArray)
                              .filter(x -> {
        Long remainingDuplication = maxValues.computeIfPresent(x, (y, count) -> count - 1);
        return remainingDuplication == null || remainingDuplication < 0;
    });

    return IntStream.concat(head, tail).toArray();
}
```

Above example of course sorts the entire input array, but keeps the order of unsorted elements stable.

Another stream example using priority queue (as others mentioned) reduces the runtime complexity:

```
Collection<Integer> sortPartially(int[] inputArray, int sortedPartLength) {
    Queue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(sortedPartLength);

    Deque<Integer> result = IntStream.of(inputArray).boxed().map(x -> {
        pq.add(x);
        return pq.size() > sortedPartLength ? pq.poll() : null;
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));

    Stream.generate(pq::remove).limit(sortedPartLength).forEach(result::addFirst);

    return result;
}
```

If there are duplicates in the input array, the order of unsorted elements can change.

Comment: Sorry, but what is `IntStream`? I use java 8 and it throws an error.

Comment: @curveball `java.util.stream.IntStream` is a part of JDK 8

Comment: It's not obvious from the question but if the array contains duplicates, like {1,2,3,4,5,5,5} you might lose one or two of the largest elements

Comment: @Eritrean they are unique, I corrected the original post.

Comment: @Eritrean I tested {1,2,3,4,5,5,5} and expect {5,5,5,1,2,3,4} as a result. And that's the result of the function. What do you mean?

Comment: @Curveball Regarding [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html): It is a stream of unboxed integers.

Comment: @SME_Dev In my example I would assume that the three largest elements are 5, 4 and 3 and not only the three repeated 5 so that the result is {5,5,5,4,3,1,2}. But you can ignore my comment because the OP has already clarified that the elements are unique.

Comment: Test input `{1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5}` with `sortedPartLength=2` and verify the output. Downvoting for the functional flaw.

Comment: @Naman not only [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809071/1059372)...

Comment: @Naman see update. Added complexity which wasn't asked for, but I hope you're a little happier now.

Comment: That’s the moment we should ask, why the OP wants a *partial sort*. According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805685/partially-sort-an-array-in-descending-order-using-java-stream-api/57806483#comment102043389_57805685), the OP doesn’t care about the order of the remaining elements, so a full sort would be in the range of valid results. So why not just do a full sort? I suppose, the goal is to improve the performance. In that regard, this solution missed the goal entirely, as the first operation that is performed, is a full sort, followed by a lot of other operations…

Answer (score 4):

Though the code is longer than the accepted answer, it does a lot less sorting: for big arrays this will matter:

```
private static int[] partiallySorted(int[] input, int bound) {
    int[] result = new int[input.length];

    int i = -1;
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(bound, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    for (int x : input) {
        pq.add(x);
        if (pq.size() > bound) {
            int el = pq.poll();
            result[bound + ++i] = el;
        }
    }

    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        result[--bound] = pq.poll();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will look at this more in depth later. Now I am overwhelmed with all this java stuff...

Comment: Apart from streams, there are few ways to solve the problem certainly. Other than that, is this tested on the inputs? Doesn't seem to be appropriate with the `result[--b] = el` and `result[bound++] = i` combination in the code. Would get back to you with the details in a while

Comment: @Naman edited. actually yes, tested both your input and OP's.

Comment: I’d say, this is way more efficient than the accepted answer, even for small arrays. The accepted answer’s solution even bears a full sort operation at the beginning, on boxed values, before doing lots of stuff to emulate a partial sort operation. It does maintain the original order though, but according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805685/partially-sort-an-array-in-descending-order-using-java-stream-api/57806483#comment102043389_57805685) that’s not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know how to partially sort an array of primitive integers in descending order using Stream API.

There is no built-in tool that lets you do this in Java. Neither in the Stream API nor in the Collections API. You either need to implement it on your own or change your approach.

> I said Stream API because I want it to be written nicely.

Using Java 8 Streams does not mean that your code will be *written nicely*. Streams are ***not*** universal tools. Sometimes they offer enhanced readability and sometimes you have to use something else.

> Another approach I could think about - is to use a custom comparator limiting the number of sorted elements.

That can't be done, since `Comparator` does not know how many elements have been sorted. Simply counting the calls will not give you any meaningful information in this regard.

---

What I would suggest is implementing something like `C++`'s `std::partial_sort`, which is most likely based on the [heap approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528591/creating-a-max-heap-using-java).

Comment: *"Using Java 8 Streams does not mean that your code will be written nicely."* - Conciseness and expressiveness is one of its purposes, not the major one, though.

Comment: *"Comparator does not know how many elements have been sorted"* - It may know it, which would make it stateful. However, Stream API wants us to write stateless `Comparator`s. I don't downvote any answers, btw.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I wholeheartedly agree, but simply using Streams won't make your code better. They may, certainly, but it's not a rule. Not everything that *can* be rewritten using Streams should be. These are rare cases, but they do happen.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko can you please provide an example of such `Comparator`? To know how many elements have been sorted it would need to inspect the collection it is used for sorting and the checks could be potentially deadly for performance, which seems to be of concern here. Not that it has to do anything with the sole fact of those potentially existing. Are the stateful `Comparator`s simply checking the referenced collection, or you have something tricky up your sleeve?

Comment: I had in mind a comparator that would remember 3 biggest numbers that came through its `compare` method (no direct collection traversal, but a comparator with side-effects)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko wouldn't that require a Comparator to know exactly the algorithm used for sorting? For example, how can it know that after, let's say, 100 `compare` calls, all elements were visited? How would it **stop** the algorithm? The order of elements passed to `Comparator` are determined by sorting algorithm and may vary a lot. I do not think this behaviour is achievable by a sole `Comparator` that does not know the **exact** algorithm that is using it.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko A stateful comparator violates the contract of comparator itself, regardless of which API you use. In the current implementation, it doesn’t matter whether you use `Stream.sorted`, `List.sort`, or `Arrays.sort`, it will end up at the same code anyway, which will break with a stateful comparator. But once you’ve taught your comparator how to remember the 3 biggest numbers, you did the crucial work anyway. Combining the facility to remember the 3 biggest numbers with a single linear traversal is way more efficient than a sort operation.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko actually, the requirement that repeated evaluations return the same result is so fundamental that it is not even mentioned explicitly. But all other requirements, like [“`sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))`” and “`((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) are building on it. A comparator may silently record encountered values when it doesn’t affect the order, but that would be less efficient than just doing a linear pass.

Answer (score 1):

I  would save the three largest elements in a set and then define my own comparator.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] input = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(input).boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Comparator<Integer> customComp = (a,b) -> { 
        if(set.contains(a) && set.contains(b)){ return a.compareTo(b);}
        else if(set.contains(a)){ return 1;}
        else if(set.contains(b)){ return -1;}
        else { return 0;}
    };
    int[] sorted = Arrays.stream(input).boxed().sorted(customComp.reversed()).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this very nicely using streams. Here is one way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    List<Integer> originalValues = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        originalValues.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).ifPresent(v -> {
            list.add(v);
            originalValues.remove(v);
        });
    }
    list.addAll(originalValues);

    System.out.println(list);
    // [5, 4, 3, 1, 2]
}
```

Comment: it gives an error like `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` at `.max(Integer::compareTo).ifPresent(v -> {`

Comment: Not sure how. It works fine for me. Maybe try `.stream().mapToInt(v->v).max()`

Comment: @curveball this code uses `Integer[]`, not `int[]`. You can’t use `int[]` with `Arrays.asList`.